# C# set a custom embedded cursor

Tags: c#, cursor, embedded-resource

I would like to use a custom embedded cursor, i tried this code, but i just see the normal cursor:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Cursor mycur = new Cursor(GetType(), "mycursor.cur");
  this.Cursor = mycur;
}
```

(the method is called from initalizecomponent)
Why this isn't work, any other ideas? 
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Did you add that cursor as a resource?

Comment: Look in the Output window.  Do you see a "First chance exception" message?  Move this code to the constructor where it belongs.  Also makes it debuggable on a 64-bit operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: 
[how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)

and then put the stream instead of the file name string `"mycursor.cur"`